# Cannot connect to REST API on development server from Real Android Device in Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I  have Visual Studio Community 2019 installed with Xamarin 16.0.2.95.
I am developing an Xamarin .Forms app that connects to ASP.NET MVC Rest API.
I am currently only testing with with a Samsung Galaxy Note 9 device.

The problem I am having is I cant seem to connect to the Rest API from the app on the samsung device.

I am using Fiddler to view traffic and have Fiddler as a proxy for the Samsung so I can see all traffic
from the Samsung.

If I go into web browser on the samsung device it works and I get json returned but not from app on the device.

i am using Conveyor by Keyoti and this gives me the ip to Rest Api

https://192.168.1.4:45457/api/Orders/1

This is method that I call.
No error messages occur.

```
public async void GetOrder()
    {
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler());

       var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://192.168.1.4:45457/api/Orders/1");

        Order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(response);

        client.Dispose();
}
```

I hope I have given enough info for someone to help. I am in the learning stage.

Malcolm

Comment: The API is not working. is it setup on local?

Comment: Hi , do you [required permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=macos) about [**INTERNET**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRYbV.png) in project for android .

Comment: Yes I have set Internet and Network Access permissions but same problem. Any other ideas?